# Timestamp appears to be wrong on some log files

Tags: server, log, timestamp

When I use scp to remotely check my server logs, the "last changed" timestamp on some files appears to be set in the future. I've double checked the local time and timezone settings on both my server and the computer I'm logging in from and both are correct. Is there a reason the timestamp is wrong, and is this something I should worry about?

Comment: Could you specify what logs and who creates them?